# How do you say there are "x" number of days until some event or something?

Tags: usage

How do you say something like: "There are 8 days until I go on vacation"? I'm pretty much confused on the how to say "x days/hrs/weeks until blank".

Answer (score 4):

> 誕生日まで（あと）８日です。
>   There are 8 (more) days until my birthday.

(Sidenote: ８日 can be pronounced 「ようか」 or 「はちにち」, though I think NHK recommends 「はちにち」 for time intervals like this.)

Comment: When referring to periods of time it is worth to use 間, so that you get ８日間 which is pronounced as ようかかん。Never heard anyone to say it はちにち by the way.

Comment: @Rilakkuma I think both appear with about equal frequency, because you can think of it as either an interval or an ordinal in this context.

Comment: 間 is usually omitted in the "[XまであとY日](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=発売まであと)" expression ("XまであとY週間" is OK, though). I couldn't find anything authoritative about this, but ようか and はちにち here in this context does sound natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct translation, but you could say it like

> 今日の[８日後]{よう・か・ご}は旅行(の)スタート！　→　8 days from today is the start of my vacation!